# how can I show and hide popupWindow

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

Instead of creating an object each time is how can I show and hide the same popup window.
This is how I created the window.
I don't want to dismiss(); and recreate the window each time for performance reasons.

```
popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
               popupView, 
               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: There is no methods that would allow you to do this easily. [Look here in the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html). If showing/dismissing is causing performance issues there there is probably a bigger issue

Comment: @codeMagic do you see any problem with the accepted answer below?

Comment: Does it work because it shouldn't?

Comment: setting it to invisible works but not setting it to visible. Why is it so?

Comment: Oh, I see. That is changing the visibility of the `View` not the actual `PopUpWindow` so it will still be there *over* the activity window. So, the `PopUpWindow` object is probably being dismissed after you touch the screen again and so you can't change it back to visible. This is not a good option

Comment: Can you give some context as to why you would need to show/dismiss it often and what the performance issue is? Maybe there is a better way

Comment: I want this to appear everytime the user launches the application or comes back from background as a splash screen and I want to draw a lot of stuff in there.

Comment: I don't see that being a performance issue but have you tried using an Activity with a Dialog theme instead of a Dialog in an Activity?

Comment: new activity is not an option as it causes my application to background if I add a new activity on top of my activity. I am porting an iOS app to android so I might have a lot of different issues than just working on native android app

Comment: have you tried ProgressDialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the view around as making it should be the expensive thing and just make a new popupWindow with the old view every time